# Flex 4 Item Renderer background colour - states do not work

Tags: css, apache-flex, colors, flex4, states

I have an item renderer with the following states:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State name="hovered"/>
    <s:State name="selected"/>
</s:states>
```

I am trying to change background color of the items when hovered and selected. I added the following lines to the Item renderer opening tag:

```
contentBackgroundColor.hovered="0xff0018"
contentBackgroundColor.selected="0xffff11"
```

Nothing happens when hovered or selected other than default item renderer behaviour (grey color). If I lets say increase the width of the image within:

```
width.hovered="100"
```

The image gets resized as expected, how can I achieve the effect I am looking for?

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                xmlns:objects="objects.*"
                creationComplete="itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                width="100%" height="100%"
                contentBackgroundColor.hover="0xff0018" focusColor="0xff00ff" contentBackgroundAlpha="0.8"
                dataChange="refreshView()">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="hovered"/>
        <s:State name="selected"/>
    </s:states>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <objects:EmbededImages id="embImages"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import events.MyEventDispatcher;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                //this.parentApplication.MyEventDispatcher.Dispatcher.addEventListener(CastUpdateEvent.UPDATED, refreshView);
                refreshView();
            }

            public function refreshView():void
            {
                var profileImage:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("Movie Manager Settings\\profiles\\" + data.@id + ".jpg");
                if(profileImage.exists)
                {
                    personImage.source = profileImage.nativePath as String;
                }
                else
                {
                    personImage.source = embImages.portrait;
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Image id="personImage" top="7" bottom="7" left="7" height="70" width="50"/>
    <s:RichText left="70" height="100%" width="100" text="{data.@name}" textAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle" paddingRight="5"/>
    <s:RichText right="10" height="100%" width="100" text="{data.@character}" textAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: contentBackgroundColor is a style and width is a property.  I wonder if that makes a difference?  That said, you should post your full itemRenderer's code.  What exactly are you setting the contentBackgroundColor on?

Comment: I added full item renderer code, these styles work perfectly in a component so seems odd, it doesn't work in item renderer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this works

```
<s:GridItemRenderer currentState="normal" >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function state1_enterStateHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
            bc.setStyle("backgroundColor",0xff0018);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal"/>
    <s:State enterState="state1_enterStateHandler(event)" name="myState"/>
    <s:State name="selected"/>
</s:states>

<s:BorderContainer id="bc" left="0" right="0" height="{this.height}"/>
<s:Button click="this.currentState = 'prova'"/>
```

Comment: That will work indeed, but I will want to move the styles to external css file at some point can you see why the code I added doesn't work?

Comment: i hope i have understood your question
you can define your syle in css in this way:

.itemRendererRollover{
    backgroundColor:0xff0018
}

In your item renderer, inside the state1_enterStateHandler() method, just type bc.setStyle("styleName","itemRendererRollover")

Alternatively, it should work also removing the method state1_enterStateHandler() and defining the "styleName.state" property in the mxml declaration of th bc component in this way:
<s:BorderContainer styleName.myState = ".itemRendererRollover" styleName.myState2 = ".itemRendererRollover2" ..and so on/>

Let me know if works!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the CSS:

```
s|ItemRenderer:hovered {
 contentBackgroundColor: #ff0018;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use in css :

`.myItemRendererStyleName:selected #idOflabelInItemRenderer {
contentBackgroundColor:#ff0000;
}`

and in mxml :

`<s:ItemRenderer styleName="myItemRendererStyleName" .... />`

`<s:Label id="idOflabelInItemRenderer" includeIn="normal,selected" />`